# How to safely compare a string defined in a variable to a string loaded from a text file with unknown encoding in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I have a configuration file with key value pair like below:

```
PARAM1=FOO
PARAM2=BAR
```

My Python script load those values compare them to a string. Strangely this comparison fail, so I suspect an encoding/decoding issue with value loaded from text file. How to safely perform this comparison?

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
# test.py

import os
import io

pattern = 'PARAM1'

file_list = io.open('list.txt','r',encoding='utf8')

for line in file_list.readlines():
    if pattern in line:
        value = line.split('=')[1]

file_list.close()

if value == 'FOO':
    print("[DEBUG] Valid")
else:
    print("[DEBUG] Invalid")

print("[DEBUG] Value: %s" %(value))
assert value == 'FOO', "%s is not equal to 'FOO'" %(value)
```

**Output**

```
[DEBUG] Invalid
[DEBUG] Value: FOO

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line XX, in <module>
    assert value == 'FOO', "%s is not equal to 'FOO'" %(value)
AssertionError: FOO
 is not equal to 'FOO'
```

Comment: `.readlines()` returns lines with the line ending still there, and nothing you've done with the line strips it off.  So you're comparing `"FOO\n"` with `"FOO"`.

Comment: Change `%s` to `%r` and the error message will make this more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the line break in the error message. You didn't strip the newline from the value after you read the line from the file.

```
for line in file_list:
    line = line.strip()
    if pattern in line:
        value = line.split('=')[1]
```

You don't need to call `readlines`; the file itself is iterable, so you don't need a pre-read list of its contents.

Comment: thanks, changing to %r made the \n character visible.